# What program can stabilize video?

Tags: video-editing

I like to make some OC occasionally, particularly create fun GIFs. I have the whole pack of Adobe programs at my disposal, and I'm not sure which would be easier to use or produce better results. I see people recommend to use both After Effects and Premier Pro for video stabilization, and I'd like to know the pros and cons of each. Also, I'm particularly interested in working with GIF format.

Answer (score 5):

I simply use YouTube: I upload the video privately,apply stabilization and download it once it is processed. It's free and online, but they re-encode the video and the max resolution is 1080p.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs - the maximum available quality is MP4 container/1080p/H.264/3-4Mbps/AAC 192kbps audio

Comment: @nodiscc Yes, thanks I guess I should have added this in the answer. Online (free) solutions virtually always have some additional limitations... (my account is even limited to 15 minutes due to stupid DMCA claims that I can't get rid of) that's why I voted user1306322's answer. I've mostly mentioned YouTube as it is straightforward to use and free :) I would be curious to see how Adobe and Youtube's stabilization feature compare though, put aside those limitations.

Answer (score 4):

Both Adobe Premier Pro and After Effects have "Warp Stabilizer" effect with various settings. Importing GIFs may be tricky. I resolved this by first splitting the GIF into a sequence of separate frames using Photoshop and import them as video in AE.

Answer (score 1):

After effects, Premiere and Sony Vegas have video stabilization tools, but I use Deshaker because it is free and produces more flexible results.  The downside, is that it will take more effort to tweak and configure Deshaker and the virtualdub software.

I made a quick video tutorial: 
http://youtu.be/QeJrr62wI5I